# Fubini's theorem on expectation of complex exponential Brownian motion

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

I am trying to show that for a one dimensional Brownian motion $B_t$, ${Ee^{\zeta B_t}}$ is analytic using Morera's theorem, and
$$Ee^{\zeta B_t}=e^{t \zeta^2/2}$$ for all $\zeta \in \mathbb{C}$.

The given facts are that $Ee^{i\xi B_t}=e^{-t\xi^2/2}$ for all $t\ge 0$ and $\xi \in \mathbb{R}$.

Also, using the fact that $e^{|c||y|}e^{-y^2/2} \le e^{c^2}e^{-y^2/4}$ is integrable, I get that
$E e^{|\zeta|\cdot |B_t|}<\infty$ for all $\zeta \in \mathbb{C}$.

So now, since $e^{t\zeta^2/2}$ is analytic and agrees with $Ee^{\zeta B_t}$ on the real line, the proof is complete if I show that $Ee^{\zeta B_t}$ is also analytic.

I have learned that this can be proven using Morera's theorem, but that requires Fubini and I don't know how to show that the assumptions for Fubini hold. Actually I don't know how Fubini works for complex functions.
How do I prove this theorem?

I have asked this question before [For a one-dimensional Brownian motion $B_t$ $Ee^{\zeta B_t}=e^{t\zeta ^2/2}\; \text{for all} \; \zeta \in \mathbb{C}.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1832633/for-a-one-dimensional-brownian-motion-b-t-ee-zeta-b-t-et-zeta-2-2-t) but there is no discussion on the analyticity of $Ee^{\zeta B_t}$.

Comment: Fubini for complex functions: just apply Fubibi to real and imaginary parts.

Comment: @geetha290krm Then don't we need to show that $\int_\gamma E|e^{(a+ib)B_t}|<\infty?$

Comment: Continuous functions are integrable over compact sets.